# Как ограничить скорость скачивания на клиенте?

Tags: c++, .net, node.js, winapi

Как при скачивании файла по http ограничить скорость скачивания на клиенте?
Цель - контролировать загруженность канала.

Интересуют все возможные варианты реализации.

Устраивают .NET, C++, winapi, node.js.

---

Какая технология позволяет вмешиваться в обработку tcp-пакетов с минимальными усоиями?

Comment: Поставьте nginx и установите опцию `limit_rate`.

Comment: @Etki, на клиенте, а не на сервере. И для конкретного соединения, а не для всех. Каким образом тут должен помочь nginx?

Comment: Втупил, есть такое.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы не будете читать из tcp-сокета, то входной буфер переполнится, о чем драйвер tcp уведомит сервер, установив нулевое окно приема. При нулевом окне приема сервер перестанет отправлять данные.

Иными словами, если читать из сокета медленно - то и по сети данные будут идти тоже медленно.

Comment: Т. е. сначала некоторое время ждём, чтобы буфер заполнился, а потом начинаем читать данные с интересующей скоростью?

Comment: Еще проще. Сразу читаем данные с интересующей нас скоростью. Протокол TCP не даст серверу посылать данные быстрее (с точностью до размера буфера).

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае, наверное, никак, кроме разве что использования каких-либо внешних ограничителей, типа прокси. Но можно попробовать воспользоваться обходным путём, например, использовать технику [частичного скачивания](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#.D0.A7.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_GET) ресурса, где каждую часть забирать через вручную созданные паузы. Следует отметить при этом, что обозначенные части ресурса всё равно будут скачиваться на максимуме возможной скорости, плюс накладные расходы на отправку нескольких управляющих запросов, вместо одного в традиционном случае. То есть для мелких по размеру файлов - это однозначно не вариант.

Comment: Как же никак, если менеджеры закачек и торрент-клиенты ограничивать скорость умеют?

Comment: Правильно, делят ресурс на части и скачивают, распределяя время.

Comment: Нет, менеджеры закачек точно ради ограничения скорости на части не делят. Они же могут качать ресурсы, где после разрыва сеодинения ссылка станет невалидной. Вообще, нагуглил, что такое возможно на уровни tcp и  там же нашёл ссылку http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_tuning, но не понял, как это использовать.

Comment: Менеджеры закачек отправляют запрос на получение столько-то байт с таким-то сдвигом от начала. Вот и всё деление. Ваша ссылка - это описание физического лимита канала связи, плюс ситуации с потерянными пакетами. Причём здесь искусственное ограничение, непонятно. Да и как вообще возможно, указать пакету идти по проводам с определённой скоростью. Нет такого в природе. Он всегда пойдёт на максимуме скорости, что позволяет канал связи.

Comment: Менеджеры закачек умеют скачивать файл одним запросом с ограничением скорости. Или я неправильно понимаю, что ты говоришь о нескольких запросах с указанием content-range? Что касается скорости - да, каждый пакет пойдёт на максимуме скорости, но ведь пакеты не обязаны идти подряд (в смысле, без задержки между пакетами). Как вообще обеспечивается нужная задержка в соответствии со скоростью соединения? И ещё, там же требуется подтверждение приёма пакета - что если делать задержку перед отправкой этого подтверждения?

Comment: Вероятно Вы путаете запрос и соединение. Соединение может быть одно, а в его рамках может быть несколько запросов. Тот же http позволяет сохранять соединение открытым (если это поддерживает сервер) при отправке в заголовке атрибута "keep-alive". Пакеты всегда идут на максимуме скорости, а вот время между отправками запросов клиент может регулировать. Тем самым, получив одну часть ресурса, можно подождать какое-то время и отправить запрос на получение следующей части. Таким образом, сумарная скорость будет как бы ограничена. Это вот и есть искусственное ограничение скорости.

Comment: Для http не нужно никаких подтверждений, если только Вы не реализуете свой протокол поверх него. Сам же http работает поверх tcp и именно последний проверяет корректность доставки пакетов.

Comment: Нет, разницу между соединением и запросом я знаю. Ладно, что будет, если отправить поддтверждение получения tcp-пакета не сразу по его получении, а с какой-то задержкой? Естественно, подразумевается не слишком большая задержка, чтобы отправитель не решил, что пакет потерян.

Comment: Да, я говорил именно о подтверждении на уровне tcp, а не http.

Comment: Ничего не произойдёт. Вторая сторона подождёт это время, на которое Вы задержите отправку. Этакая эмуляция некачественного канала связи. Ну конечно если не слишком долго. Другое дело, если я не ошибаюсь, это уже уровень модулей ядра. Стоит ли овчинка выделки, если можно регулировать скорость стандартными средствами.

Comment: "Вторая сторона подождёт это время, на которое Вы задержите отправку." - т. е. как раз то, что я хотел получить? :)

Comment: Tcp гарантирует доставку отдельных пакетов. Это значит, что даже повторная отправка потерянного пакета может быть осуществлена. В каких случаях и при какой задержке возможно влезать со своими паузами, лучше ознакомиться со спецификацией протокола.